# Google BigQuery move to SQL Server, Big Data table optimisation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, indexing, bigdata

I have a curious question and as my name suggests I am a novice so please bear with me, oh and hi to you all, I have learned so much using this site already.

I have an MSSQL database for customers where I am trying to track their status on a daily basis, with various attributes being recorded in several tables, which are then joined together using a data table to create a master table which yields approximately 600million rows.

As you can imagine querying this beast on a middling server (Intel i5, SSD HD OS, 2tb 7200rpm HD, Standard SQL Server 2017) is really slow. I was using Google BigQuery, but that got expensive very quickly. I have implemented indexes which have somewhat sped up the process, but still not fast enough. A simple select distinct on customer id for a given attribute is still taking 12 minutes on average for a first run.

The whole point of having a daily view is to make it easier to have something like tableau or QLIK connect to a single table to make it easy for the end user to create reports by just dragging the required columns. I have thought of using the main query that creates the master table and parameterizes it, but visualization tools aren't great for passing many variables.

This is a snippet of the table, there are approximately 300,000 customers and a row per day is created for customers who join between 2010 and 2017. They fall off the list if they leave.

My questions are:

1) should I even bother creating a flat file or should I just parameterize the query.

2) Are there any techniques I can use aside from setting the smallest data types for each column to keep the DB size to a minimal.

3) There are in fact over a hundred attribute columns, a lot of them, once they are set to either a 0 or 1, seldom change, is there another way to achieve this and save space?

4)What types of indexes should I have on the master table if many of the attributes are binary

any ideas would be greatly received.

[image]

Comment: You should summarize this table into a type-2 table with version effective and end dates.  However, you should really find someone who understands databases to help with this problem.

Comment: Have you tried nonclustered columnstore index for your select distinct query? Or clustered columnstore index for saving disk space?

Comment: I've never come across a type-2 table only diabetes. I will have to do some research into it. The table is a read-only table once created.

Comment: I have indexed the Fact tables that create the main master table and that does speed up the creation of the Master table. I have also created non-clustered columnstore indexes. I have read somewhere that you can infact add all of the columns to a columnstore index.

Comment: I think my main issues is that the query used to create the main table runs into quite a few hundred if not thousand lines and joins together around 20 tables. it was created so that others can easily query the database without having as much experience in writing SQL. But, already as the data grows, so will the Master table. Are there constructs in SQL which can be used int he same way as a date table to enumerate a date range into its constituent days yet retaining the simplicity of querying a big flat table like the one in the diagram?